# Bind linq data to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I know this has been asked before, but I am missing a step in databinding a LINQ query into a dropdown list.

The error was that it was not finding the subject.

```
  var querydd = from b in com.Communications
                select b.subject;

  notesdd = new DropDownList();
  notesdd.ID = "notesdd" + i.ToString(); //Subject line
  notesdd.DataSource = querydd;
  notesdd.DataTextField = "subject";
  notesdd.DataBind();
```

Comment: And what is not working as expected?

Comment: What's `i` here? Also you need to set `DataValueField` property.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Sorry, the error is system.string does not contain a property with the name subject.  This is after changing DataTextField to DataValueField

Comment: Please add that information to your original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linq query creates just a collection of strings, not objects with property "subject". So what you should do is just bind this list to the drop down directly:

```
notesdd = new DropDownList();
notesdd.DataSource = querydd.ToList();
notesdd.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

The data that you bind to `notesdd` does indeed - as the error tells you - not contain a property with the name `subject`. Why?

While `from b in com.Communications select b` would return a collection of objects that contain a `subject`-property, you are explicitly selecting only that property from your objects! This results in a list of `<whatever type subject has>`.

So either change your query to the one I stated above or change your `DataValueField`, i.e. don't specify it at all!